# jdbc inbound adapter with a stored procedure cursor

Tags: spring-integration

Jdbc inbound channel adapter relies on the update query to mark the already processed records and thats how we can retrieve only the non-processed records in the subsequent polls. This makes sense but I am working with a table that doesnt have a column that I can modify to indicate this record being processed.

I was wondering if I can use a stored procedure which returns a cursor and somehow that will help with not having to load all the lets say million records in memory and still be able to process lets say 1000 every poll.

Edit: I am working with oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use stored procedure on the matter. For this purpose Spring Integration suggests `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter>` component.

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/stored-procedures-oracle) you can find the sample.

Comment: Still not clear if the stored procedure uses a cursor what does that mean for the adapter. Will it still fetch all records in one attempt or be able to poll the stored procedure multiple times and get next set of rows to process

Comment: No. Each `poll` invokes procedure and it depends of the last one, how to return data from DB. If it is `cursor` you should provide a `RowMapper` to populate that data as a `List<?>`. And adapter will send a message with that list a a part of `Map<String, ?>` payload. See more info in our docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures